# Getting an error, while loading dataset mnist() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load dataset MNIST in R using

```
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

but getting an error every time ….

[image: Error]

Comment: Tried this again (as follows) after loading "reticulate", but still the same. Could someone please help to comment on it ? 
np <- reticulate::import("numpy")
np$version$full_version

devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")

tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
then again do
np <- reticulate::import("numpy")
np$version$full_version

Comment: Did you read the manual page? I appears that the function may require a `path=` argument.

Comment: The default is `dataset_mnist(path = "mnist.npz")` where `path` is one very specific path.

Comment: I see.. Thanks !    I tried it and it worked.